# establish socket connection to streaming server and iphone

Tags: iphone, sockets, streaming

I want to establish socket connection to streaming server (with iphone ) and want to download its content like image,.css,etc to iphone. Any Idea or sample code is can help me. I need to write code for client only.

Comment: What kind of streaming server? HTTP? RTMP? Something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Establish Connection as follows and change the urlStr to your server URL

```
    NSString *urlStr = @"http://192.168.0.108";
    NSURL *website = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
    CFReadStreamRef readStream;
    CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (CFStringRef)[website host], 1234, &readStream, &writeStream);
    NSInputStream *inputStream = (NSInputStream *)readStream;
    NSOutputStream *outputStream = (NSOutputStream *)writeStream;
    [inputStream setDelegate:self];
    [outputStream setDelegate:self];
    [inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [inputStream open];
    [outputStream open];
```

Make Use of NSStream Delegate as follows to read data

```
- (void)stream:(NSStream *)stream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode {

    switch(eventCode) {
        case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:

        {

            NSLog(@"Bytes Available");


            uint8_t b[1024];
            unsigned int len = 0;
            NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
            len = [(NSInputStream *)stream read:b maxLength:1024];


            if(!len) {
                if ([stream streamStatus] != NSStreamStatusAtEnd)
                {

                }
            } else {

                [data appendBytes:(const void *)b length:len];
                int bytesRead;
                bytesRead += len;
               //make use of data here

        }
        }

            break;

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have used this as you suggest. But how do I know that the connection is successfully established.  I have write this method- "(void)stream:(NSStream *)stream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode" but it is not called when performing execution.I have declare NSStreamDelegate in interface.Please Suggest.

Comment: in .h file use protocol <NSStreamDelegate>,

Comment: Put breakpoint in the line [inputStream setDelegate:self]; if inputStream and outputStream are not equal to "nil" it conforms the connection is established.

Comment: And to test the app write some data to the socket at the server side. If streams are nil it means that the url you are using is wrong are server is down.

Comment: Make sure that the port number is same on both server and client side,

Comment: Yes, The debugger is not showing nil. But stream:handleEvent is not calling I have test it with debugger and write NSLog statement there. Also I have use NSStreamDelegate protocol in .h file.

Comment: Any Idea for this.Please Suggest.

Comment: I don't know this is the exact code i used in my app and it is working, go through following link once, it might you. http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/43551/1954

Answer (score -2):

Slightly changes in the code I used:

```
NSHost *host = [NSHost hostWithName:[website host]];
        [NSStream getStreamsToHost:host 
                      port:8766 
                       inputStream:iStream
                      outputStream:oStream];
```

Instead of

```
CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (CFStringRef)[website host], 1234, &readStream, &writeStream);
    NSInputStream *inputStream = (NSInputStream *)readStream;
    NSOutputStream *outputStream = (NSOutputStream *)writeStream;
```